# Web Speech Recognition code not transcribing speech

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to use HTML5 Web Speech API's Speech Recognition.

I can't figure out why this code is not working. It is triggering the permission for requesting access to the microphone, but when I speak nothing is transcribed.

When I look in the console, there are no errors, but the console.log that happens when the speech recognition is stopped is triggered.

I think it is stopping prematurely.

Does anyone know what is going on and why it is not working?

Here is the JS:

It depends on webspeech.js, which is included in the jsfiddle.

Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2sMXZ/3/

Here is the implementation code:

```
var reco = new WebSpeechRecognition;
$('#mic').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
    reco.toggleStartStop();
});
var interim_transcript = '';
reco.recognition.onresult = function(event){
    for(var i = event.resultIndex; i<event.results.length; ++i){
        if(event.results[i].isFinal) reco.stop();
        else interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
    }
}
$('#interim_span').html(interim_transcript);
console.log(interim_transcript);
reco.recognition.onend = function(e){
    //$('#mic').removeClass('red');
    console.log('done');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $('#interim_span').html(interim_transcript) is called every interim results are emitted.

Second, when event.results[i].isFinal is true, it has a result as well.

Try

```
var reco = new WebSpeechRecognition;
$('#mic').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
    reco.toggleStartStop();
});
var interim_transcript = '';
reco.recognition.onresult = function(event){
    for(var i = event.resultIndex; i<event.results.length; ++i){
        if(event.results[i].isFinal) reco.stop();
        interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
    }
    $('#interim_span').html(interim_transcript);
    console.log(interim_transcript);
}

reco.recognition.onend = function(e){
    //$('#mic').removeClass('red');
    console.log('done');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2sMXZ/11/ The interim_transcript is logged in the console on end or on even click of `#mic`, but it is not being written to the html of interim_span. Any idea why? Or how I can fix it?

Comment: final_span and interim_span are children of results. I think they are replaced by reco.statusText("results");

Comment: Thank you, now it writes to the spans, but it is repeated. How can I get it to only write the speech once, right after it is said? http://jsfiddle.net/2sMXZ/14/

Comment: the interimResults is enabled. So you have to initialize the `interim_transcript` before appending `transcript`. I updated the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/2sMXZ/15